# add chat feature in sipdroid using openfire

Tags: android, chat, openfire

I am beginner for android application developing.I want to add chat feature in sipdroid using openfire.Can anybody help me how to start to do this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openfire uses the XMPP protocol, so you may [start on reading how](http://xmpp.org/internet-drafts/draft-saintandre-sip-xmpp-im-00.html) to incorporate XMPP in SIP.

Apart from the above article, you can look around for software sip clients that [already have this feature](http://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/src) and educate from their source code.

Also a good reference is the [XMPP java api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview) overview.

Comment: if possible can you give me your e-mail id ? otherwise i can send my source code for verification